# Folder still visible after deleting in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-management

This has been happening for the last few days.

Once I `shift + del` a folder, it doesn't disappear in the GUI. Double clicking the remaining icon, returns an error message:

`C:\Users\<name>\Documents\<parent>\<folder> is not accessible. Access is denied.`

Restarting the computer removes the folder from the GUI, but I need a solution that doesn't involve a reboot.

Right clicking and bringing up properties tells me the folder occupies 0 bytes and is read only. Folder is not shared. I am not allowed to view security tab because I don't have permissions.

Also `remove-item` in Powershell doesn't work. I did the following.

```
PS parent> Remove-Item -Recurse -Path folder -Force
```

But I got result `Cannot find path C:\...\parent\folder because it doesn't exist. ----- ItemNotFoundException`

But `Get-ChildItem` did indeed return the folder, i.e it recognized the deleted folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

The folder is managed propably by the Windows Application itself (if this is the case, read further. If not, please be more specific of what folder it still shows up after deleting.)

If you have no use for the Windows built-in apps heres how to remove them http://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/